# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT issue when using Google Maps Geocoding

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a question on `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` when trying to obtaining the latitude and longitude via Google Geocoding. Somehow it doesn't work even if I have waited more than 24 hours. I did not exceed 2,500 requests which is the maximum - 100 at maximum.

The problem `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` only occurs on my server (webhotel). When using my local machine (localhost) I experience no problem at all.

I think there is a block somewhere, but I am uncertain. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you geocoding by IP address or are you submitting street addresses to obtain coordinates?

Comment: I am geocoding via submission of address to obtain the lat & long. I have another domain on the same webhotel-provider, and there I have not experienced any problems at all.

Comment: Thanks; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a shared server environment, it could be that others on the same IP are actively querying the Google geocoding service. That would be why, on your localhost (which has a different IP address), you are not experiencing any problems at all.

**Update (based on comment above):** Now that you mention it the inconsistency is a little weird, and I'm not 100% sure what is the cause of that. The best solution, though, is probably to look for a service that permits geocode *en masse* and, preferably, allows you to keep the results. You'll also unnecessarily spin out all your queries on any addresses that don't really exist (or you'll at least get bad coordinates).

Something I've worked on while at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) is called [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) -- it's like Google's API, but simpler to use and it only returns *valid* results (meaning you won't get coordinates for an address that doesn't exist). It's free, there's potentially no query limit, and there's never any TOS restrictions that you are likely running into here. And I'm pretty sure you won't be deducted in your account for addresses which don't verify, even though you queried it.

So that's another option that you could look into as a work-around for the limitations you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an own API key, just verify your account by adding your credit card details (*Google just uses them for verification purposes, they won't charge you, unless you purcase Google API Premier*). This raises the limit to **250,000** requests per day and gives you an unique API key and live stats.

You can do this in the [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$output= json_decode(stripcslashes(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$data['lat'].','.$data['lon'].'&sensor=false&language=ru')));
print $output->results[0]->formatted_address
```